# $\int_{}{} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

A physics problem says that the following integral is said to evaluate to: $$\int_{}{} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} dx =  \frac{2x+3}{8}\sqrt{x^2-x+1} + \frac{1}{16}\ln(2x+1+2\sqrt{x^2-x+1})$$

I can not seem to find a way that evaluates to this. I know that a integral of this form can be broken down to:

$$\int_{}{} \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}dx = Q(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} + t\int{}{}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}dx$$

Where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree one less than $P(x)$. Can anyone see a solution from this angle?

Comment: You can always check an antiderivative by differentiating.  This one does not work.

Comment: Hmm, looks like that should be 
$$ \frac{2x+3}{4}\sqrt{x^2-x+1} - \frac{1}{8} \ln (2 x - 1 + 2 \sqrt{x^2-x+1})$$

Comment: Thats what I thought!

Answer (score 3):

Equate numerator as $x^2=A(x^2-x+1)+B(2x-1)+C$

which gives $A=1, B=\frac12$ & $C=-\frac12$. Now proceed as follows
$$\int_{}{} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} dx$$
$$=\int \frac{(x^2-x+1)+\frac12(2x-1)-\frac12}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} dx$$
$$=\int\left( \sqrt{x^2-x+1} +\frac12\frac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}-\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} \right)dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\ dx +\frac12\int\frac{d(x^2-x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} -\frac12\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}}$$